# ListObjects.Add.QueryTable Source Array String

Tags: vba, excel

I will provide some context before I ask my question.

I am attempting to query an SQL Server and create a table within Excel from the data. Because I am not familiar with how to accomplish this in VBA I recorded by using Data -> Get External Data -> From Other Sources -> Microsoft Query. In the dialog box that appears, I chose a .DSN file provided to me by someone else. I then used the Microsoft Query interface to structure the query and import the data onto a worksheet.

The code in the recorded macro looked something like this. I will use generic terms instead of the actual code.

```
With Sheet2.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:= 0, Source:=Array _
    (Array("ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=ServerName;UID=userid;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Windows Operating System;WSID=SomeString"), _
    Array("A;DATABASE=DatabaseName")), Destination:=Range ("Sheet2!$A$1")).QueryTable
```

I know this is not formatted ideally, which is part of my question below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211863(v=office.12).aspx

From the above article, I know that SourceType:= 0 is an xlSrcExternal, or an external data source. This makes sense to me.

My confusion begins to arise when I get to the Source component of the Add method. From the provided article, "When SourceType = xlSrcExternal, an array of String values specifying a connection to the source, containing the following elements:

•0 - URL to SharePoint site

•1 - ListName

•2 - ViewGUID

So to begin with, what exactly is meant by "an array of String values", as the code from the recorded macro does not appear to correspond to what I thought was an array. I know that normally an array is declared something like this Array("string1", "string2", etc.). Or is the array recorded simply an array of one value? In other words Array("string1"). Does anyone know the purpose of passing an "array of string values" as opposed to just passing a string?

Also does anyone know the nuances of why the recorded macro has this particular formatting/syntax? In other words, why does it appear to have this syntax Array(Array("string1"),_ (new line) Array("string2"))? Why not just Array ("string1")? Does it have something to do with the second line being too long?

I have several more questions related to this topic, but this seemed like a good place to start..
Thank you all for any help given.

Comment: I stumbled across a forum which actually discussed the exact problem I was facing that caused me to post this. https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/62413-sql-query-visual-basic-type-mismatch-error.html From the second post, "If I remember correctly, the whole idea of passing the SQL inside an array, is because it uses elements of 255 characters each..., so, that's probably your problem here... .the SQL statement is being passed in only ONE element, and has more than 255 characters in it. "